# Clear type font usage in C#/VB.NET

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms

How do I use a [ClearType](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClearType) font in C#/[VB.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_.NET)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.DrawString("Normal style", this.Font, Brushes.Black, 50, 50);

    e.Graphics.TextRenderingHint =
         System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.ClearTypeGridFit;

    e.Graphics.DrawString("ClearType style", this.Font, Brushes.Black, 50, 100);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, to set the smoothing method to "standard," use:

```
e.TextRenderingHint = Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAliasGridFit
```